# How to run eclipse on bash on Ubuntu on Windows?

Tags: windows, eclipse, bash, ubuntu

I have eclipse installed on my windows machine, but I can't seem to use it with bash so I installed eclipse on the bash terminal by using "sudo apt-get install eclipse". It installed fine, but I can't figure out how to launch the eclipse GUI from the linux subsystem so I can use it like the windows version. I tried using Xming and exporting DISPLAY, but that didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: why don't you run eclipse on windows ?

Comment: Please describe the problem you are trying to solve; see [ask]. This sounds like an exercise in futility.

Comment: I'm trying to use bash exclusively for tasks (including tasks I currently use Windows applications for) on my windows machine so I can run bash scripts involving eclipse. Bash scripting is a lot less powerful if I can use it for neither windows applications nor Ubuntu applications.

Answer (score 1):

from what i understood from the link below, you require to update .bashrc to direct the GUI display to a X Server process. I installed xMing to run X Server from Windows 10. i also had to install gtk components that allowed me to run sublime text GUI from within WSL.

https://medium.com/@pck/how-to-use-sublime-text-3-from-command-line-with-ubuntu-bash-terminal-in-windows-10-subsystems-for-aa2ad59d088c

hope this helps

Comment: The author of that articles points to a better solutions here: https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/using-wsl-and-mobaxterm-to-create-a-linux-dev-environment-on-windows#wsl-conemu-and-mobaxterm-to-the-rescue

Comment: Still, I would have liked to have seen this answer accepted (or you to post your alternative and that to be accepted).  @Shmod people tried to help you. If you think an answer correct then accepting it will help others in future.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO you should not install eclipse by apt but simply get your desired eclipse product from from https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages , download and unzip it to your wanted location and just start eclipse.

Reasons:

1. I do not know any Linux distribution containing a newer eclipse bundled, so you are always having older versions being slower and having less features
2. You can update your eclipse installation directly inside eclipse `Check for updates`
3. You can have multiple installations at same time
4. If you want to get rid of a eclipse installation just remove the folder and you are done.

But of course you can also use bash directly in Windows with Eclipse.
Please look at
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62724163/2590615 or take a glimpse at [You Tube Video about Bash Debugging with Bash Editor eclipse plugin on a Windows 10 machine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qwjx5XFFRFw&list=PLaBYAz_I_8tF7sZVIcUv8zOVe2RMiWn-L&index=2)

*PS: I am the maintainer of the mentioned eclipse plugin*