# Run a shell script using Cygwin bash instead of Git Bash for Windows from Eclipse

Tags: windows, bash, eclipse, shell, cygwin

Clicking on a `.sh` script inside Eclipse (on Windows) executes it using Git Bash for Windows. However, I'd like to use Cygwin bash instead.

There is an option which looks like this:
[image]

I removed the shown entry for Git Bash and added an entry with a path to the Cygwin bash executable. However, this doesn't change anything - Git Bash for Windows is still used -  and after closing and opening Eclipse the Git Bash entry is there again.

How can I configure Eclipse to use Cygwin bash?

Answer (score 0):

You could also use https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/bash-editor

Here you can customize the command

[image: preference settings for bash debugger]

A description how to launch the scripts can be found at
https://github.com/de-jcup/eclipse-bash-editor/wiki/FAQ#how-can-i-execute-shell-scripts-with-bash-editor

The plugin contains also an integrated bash debugger which should work with cygwin bash as well. For the debugger in action on a Windows 10 machine you can look at [YouTube Video - Bash editor debugging on Windows 10](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qwjx5XFFRFw&list=PLaBYAz_I_8tF7sZVIcUv8zOVe2RMiWn-L&index=3&t=58s). Here you can see the default configuration done to execut git bash. Of course you have to customize start command a bit, but I think it's feasable.

*PS: I am the maintaner of the mentioned plugin*